# Index operator property on 2D Array in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm aware that in Delphi, when you want to allow the use of the index operator, [], you must do something like,

```
property Item[index: integer]: integer read GetData; default;
```

How would one go about implementing a multidimensional array in Delphi such that it allows the use of something like:

```
matrix := TMatrix<integer>.Create(3,3);
matrix[0][2] := 5;
WriteLn(matrix[0][2]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `[][]` like that.  But you can declare multiple indexes in a single property instead, eg:

```
type
  TMatrix<T> = class
  private
    function GetData(index1, index2: Integer): T;
    procedure SetData(index1, index2: Integer; value: T);
  public
    constructor Create(dim1, dim2: Integer);
    property Item[index1, index2: Integer]: T read GetData write SetData; default;
  end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
matrix := TMatrix<integer>.Create(3,3);
matrix[0, 2] := 5;
WriteLn(matrix[0, 2]);
```

Comment: Ah!  Thank you, I'm still getting the feel of this language and it's little querks like this that really trip me up.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish, you can use `[][]` to access elements. If your type is an array (two-dimensional or jagged dynamic) then this method of accessing the elements is baked into the language. For a user-defined type then you need to implement it.

There is no way to implement `[][]` in a single step in a user-defined type. What you need to do is break the process into two separate parts. The first part is to implement `[]` to return a row of your matrix. Then implement `[]` on that row to return an element. Here is an example:

```
type
  TMatrix<T> = class
  public
    type
      TRow = record
      private
        FMatrix: TMatrix<T>;
        FRowIndex: Integer;
        function GetItem(ColIndex: Integer): T; inline;
        procedure SetItem(ColIndex: Integer; const Value: T); inline;
      public
        property Items[ColIndex: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default;
      end;
  private
    FData: TArray<TArray<T>>;
    function GetRow(RowIndex: Integer): TRow; inline;
  public
    constructor Create(RowCount, ColCount: Integer);
    property Rows[RowIndex: Integer]: TRow read GetRow; default;
  end;

{ TMatrix<T>.TRow }

function TMatrix<T>.TRow.GetItem(ColIndex: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := FMatrix.FData[FRowIndex, ColIndex];
end;

procedure TMatrix<T>.TRow.SetItem(ColIndex: Integer; const Value: T);
begin
  FMatrix.FData[FRowIndex, ColIndex] := Value;
end;

{ TMatrix<T> }

constructor TMatrix<T>.Create(RowCount, ColCount: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  SetLength(FData, RowCount, ColCount);
end;

function TMatrix<T>.GetRow(RowIndex: Integer): TRow;
begin
  Result.FMatrix := Self;
  Result.FRowIndex := RowIndex;
end;
```

However, having shown that this is possible, I would suggest that is more idiomatic to use an [array property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Array_Properties) with two indices. That would mean that you would access the matrix with `M[Row,Col]` rather than `M[Row][Col]`. This particular idiom (`M[Row,Col]`) is not found in all languages so you may be unfamiliar with it. Supporting that might look like this:

```
type
  TMatrix<T> = class
  public
    type
      TRow = record
      private
        FMatrix: TMatrix<T>;
        FRowIndex: Integer;
        function GetItem(ColIndex: Integer): T; inline;
        procedure SetItem(ColIndex: Integer; const Value: T); inline;
      public
        property Items[ColIndex: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default;
      end;
  private
    FData: TArray<TArray<T>>;
    function GetRow(RowIndex: Integer): TRow; inline;
    function GetItem(RowIndex, ColIndex: Integer): T; inline;
    procedure SetItem(RowIndex, ColIndex: Integer; const Value: T); inline;
  public
    constructor Create(RowCount, ColCount: Integer);
    property Rows[RowIndex: Integer]: TRow read GetRow;
    property Items[RowIndex, ColIndex: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;

{ TMatrix<T>.TRow }

function TMatrix<T>.TRow.GetItem(ColIndex: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := FMatrix.FData[FRowIndex, ColIndex];
end;

procedure TMatrix<T>.TRow.SetItem(ColIndex: Integer; const Value: T);
begin
  FMatrix.FData[FRowIndex, ColIndex] := Value;
end;

{ TMatrix<T> }

constructor TMatrix<T>.Create(RowCount, ColCount: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  SetLength(FData, RowCount, ColCount);
end;

function TMatrix<T>.GetRow(RowIndex: Integer): TRow;
begin
  Result.FMatrix := Self;
  Result.FRowIndex := RowIndex;
end;

function TMatrix<T>.GetItem(RowIndex, ColIndex: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := FData[RowIndex, ColIndex];
end;

procedure TMatrix<T>.SetItem(RowIndex, ColIndex: Integer; const Value: T);
begin
  FData[RowIndex, ColIndex] := Value;
end;
```

Note that in this version we have elected to make `Items` be the default property. Which means that if you want to access a row you would have to name the `Rows` property explicitly: `M.Rows[RowIndex]`.